# Show/Hide Menu on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

We have menu which works on onclick/on mouse enter and on mouse leave. All of sudden after chrome got updated the menu is not working.
Especially windows XP/Chrome 40. Strangely not showing any errors is console. Please help us to get out of this.

```
var menuLeft = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s1'),
    showLeft = document.getElementById('showLeft'),
    navigationEdge = document.getElementById('navigationEdge'),
    navigationMenu = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s1'),
    body = document.body;

$("#navigationEdge").mouseenter(function () {
    classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
});

$("#cbp-spmenu-s1").mouseleave(function () {
    classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
});

showLeft.onclick = function () {
    classie.toggle(navigationEdge, 'active');
    classie.toggle(this, 'active');
    classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
};
```

Here is the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhn14qzy/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a Chrome 40 bug. I reported it yesterday, some functions aren't working (even in Developer Tools, the Toggle Element State isn't working).

Only thing I can say is... let's wait :)

- BTW, test your fiddle in Firefox, here in v35 it worked well.

Comment: I have tried in Firefox it is working. Even it is working in chrome 40 windows 7. But having trouble in windows XP.

Comment: In my Windows 7 isn't working at all. Chrome version 40.0.2214.91 m. Try to open the Dev Tools (F12) and cick on `Toggle Element State`. Here it does nothing.

Comment: Works for me, Win 7/Chrome 40.0.2214.91

Comment: @DimasPante Working for me Win 7/Chrome 40.0.2214.91 m. Also checked when Dev Tools are open. In both cases it is working.

Comment: Hah. Well, I'm with a W7 64 bits here